# Finding the complex integral along an arc

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

How can we evaluate complex expressions like these
$\int_C(Z-Z^2)dZ$ where $C$ is the upper half of the circle $|Z-2|=3$

Comment: Find a primitive of the integrand, apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: you mean substitute $Z = x+iy$ and $dZ=dx+idy$ and evaluate?

Comment: No. If $F$ is holomorphic, and $\gamma$ a (piecewise continuously differentiable) path connecting $a$ and $b$, then $$\int_\gamma F'(z)\,dz = F(b) - F(a).$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that particular $C$, write $Z=2+3 e^{i t}$, $dZ=i 3 e^{i t} dt$, where $t \in [0,\pi]$.  The integral may now be written as a simple, definite integral:

$$-i 3 \int_0^{\pi} dt \, e^{i t} (2+3 e^{i t}) (1+3 e^{i t}) = -i 3 \int_0^{\pi} dt (2 e^{i t} + 9 e^{i 2 t} + 9 e^{i 3 t}) = 30$$

Comment: you wrote $ Z=2+3e^{it}$ for $|Z-2|=3$. What would we substitute if the circle was $|Z-2-ia|=3$ {ie center=(2,a)}

Comment: $$Z=2+i a + 3 e^{i t}$$

Comment: You're making this much harder than it needs to be. Look at the comment by @DanielFischer in the original question. You are only integrating a polynomial between two points connected by a "nice" path, so there is nothing to do but evaluate $(z^2/2 - z^3/3)|_a^b$ where the path runs from $a$ to $b$